# Rails & jQuery - How to get script to remove HTML element to work multiple times

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form that displays client-side validations as the user enters information and a jQuery script that gets rid of the error messages after a period of time.

However, the script only works once per page load. I do not know much about jQuery so I am just wondering how I get it to work on every validation message?

It currently works fine for just the first error message:

This is the code verbatim in my rails .js file:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
   $(".field_with_errors label").fadeTo(300, 0).slideUp(300, function(){
    $(this).remove(); 
  });
}, 4000);
```

----Update

Just to be clear: I am using a Rails gem called Client Side Validations that generates new HTML everytime invalid data in entered in the form on this page.

Comment: What do you mean works only once? if you wrap the setTimeout in a named function to call it later it doesn't work?

Comment: I mean, once the first error message appears, the script removes it, but if another appears on the form from another field, it stays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly call your function after every error message appears, so, you could do:

```
var cleanUpErrorMessages = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".field_with_errors label").fadeTo(300, 0).slideUp(300, function(){
            $(this).remove(); 
        });
    }, 4000);
}

//...
//A new error appears, then:
cleanUpErrorMessages();
```

If you are using Client Side Validations take a look at the [callbacks](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) in the docs, but I think what you need is:

```
window.ClientSideValidations.callbacks.element.fail = function(element, message, callback) {
  callback();
  if (element.data('valid') !== false) {
    cleanUpErrorMessages();
  }
}
```